# MSSQL Thai Tone Word Check

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gets the same code value when two words are different.
Is there a way to confirm that the two words are different?

```sql
DECLARE @thai nvarchar(max) = N'กิ'
DECLARE @thai1 nvarchar(max) = N'ก'

SELECT @thai
SELECT UNICODE (LEFT (@thai, 1))
SELECT @thai1
SELECT UNICODE (LEFT (@thai1, 1))
```

Comment: Can you explain better your question. It is not very clear. Why do you do `SELECT UNICODE(LEFT...`? It selects the first character? So both return 'ก', which is correct, no?

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to confirm two words are different :

```
DECLARE @thai nvarchar(max) = N'กิ' 
DECLARE @thai1 nvarchar(max) = N'ก'

SELECT 1 WHERE @thai <> @thai1
```

1 will be selected if they are different. Otherwise, nothing can be selected.

Another way is to compare their binary form using `CAST(... AS binary)`

```
DECLARE @thai nvarchar(max) = N'กิ' 
DECLARE @thai1 nvarchar(max) = N'ก'

SELECT @thai 
SELECT CAST(@thai AS binary)
SELECT @thai1 
SELECT CAST(@thai1 AS binary)
SELECT 1 WHERE CAST(@thai AS binary) <> CAST(@thai1 AS binary)
```